# Regression Statistics model predict

Tags: regression, mathematical-statistics

Need some help answering this please!

The price and the year of manufacture for 124 randomly selected used Mazda cars were recorded in 1992. It is desired to be able to predict the 1992 price of a used Mazda car from its year of manufacture. In order to use the method of modelling using a least-squares line, it was found necessary to first transform the price variable by taking the (natural) logarithm. The relationship between ln price and year of manufacture was found to be suitable for modelling using the least-squares line. The Excel regression output is shown below. (You are reminded that log means natural logarithm, ln, unless otherwise stated.)

```
    Regression Statistics
    Multiple R                    0.901
    R Square                      0.811
    Adjusted R Square             0.809
    Standard Error                0.367
    Observations                  124

                     Coefficients       Standard Error        t Stat          P-value
    Intercept          -314.144             14.121            -22.246           0.000
Year of Manufacturer     0.163               0.007             22.879           0.000
```

Suppose another used Mazda car was manufactured in 1989. What, to the nearest whole dollar, does this model predict to be its 1992 price?

Comment: This looks like standard textbook work. Please add the `self-study` tag and read the [tag wiki info](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) to see the requirements placed on both askers and answerers for such questions here

Comment: Not to be critical of the question at all, I think it is interesting to note that the problem statement shares some of the ridiculous features found in many textbook exercises. A notable (but subtle) one is the combined use of too many digits for the model year (the year should have been referenced to some date around 2000, not 0 CE) and far too few significant digits for the output. Because "0.163" comprises all values between 0.1625 and 0.1635 and will be multiplied by a three-digit number and exponentiated, we can only conclude that the answer lies somewhere between 8,677 and 63,418!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $P_t$ be the 1992 price of a used Mazda car in the year of manufacture $t$. Then using your regression coefficients we have: $\log(P_t)=-314.144+0.163t$. Now let $t=1989$ to get $\log(P_{1989})=-314.144+0.163(1989)=10.063$. So $P_{1989}=\exp(10.063)=23,458.78$. Therefore, the predicted 1992 price of a used Mazda car and manufactured in 1989 would be almost $23,459.

Comment: Stat, this is pretty clearly a homework type question. We don't just do people's coursework for them. Please read the `self-study`  [tag wiki info](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) to see the requirements placed on both askers and answerers for such questions here. Initially, at least, our role should lean more toward giving hints and helpful suggestions.

Comment: OK, I can delete it, no problem. I deleted the other one that you commented about $cov(x,y)$, thanks for that.

Comment: Stat I wouldn't delete it; there's no point in any case since the OP has clearly already seen it - better to leave it up. My comment is more for future reference. [Once it's clear that the original asker has been put on the right track (usually, when they say something like 'oh, I get it now'), it's reasonable to give a fuller answer, or in any case after some days the questions should probably get a more complete answer.] On that other question about variance, I think you could still make some progress with the overall approach you had there.